# is it possible to scan multiple lines of input, each line a new element in an array, when you copy/paste?

Tags: java, arrays, input, java.util.scanner

Trying to populate an array with input through the scanner .nextLine() function. The problem specifications give a sample input as follows:

```
3 5 4
abc
bca
dac
dbc
cba
(ab)(bc)(ca)
abc
(abc)(abc)(abc)
(zyx)bc
```

Just as I copied and pasted that whole chunk into this box, I'd like to do the same with my code, but when I try, the code only reads in the last line. I want each line to be read in and stored in it's own index in the array, NOT a multi-line string in one index or only the last line being read in and stored (which is what is happening now).

This is my method for initializing the array, which I've tested and it works when I feed in the input line by line, but that's just really annoying to be honest.

```
public static void initialize_array(String [] arr)
{
    Scanner kbreader = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = kbreader.nextLine();
        System.out.println("this is just loading in: " + arr[i]);
    }
}
```

When I run the program, (it also takes in 3 integers at the top and I print them just to test them, but that's not important) it only registers the last line.

A screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7A0A.png)

I think I've done something like this in C, but that might be because I used scanf() and C is relatively low level so it literally had to walk through the entire chunk.

It might not be possible, but I figured I'd ask to see.

Also, just so you know this is for practice, not an actual graded assignment or anything important, so don't hold anything back. :)

Comment: how are you calling the method `initialize_array(String [] arr)` and what would be the values of `arr`

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact length of the array, then this would work:

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
scn.useDeliminator("\n");
for (int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++)
{
    arr[i] = scn.next();
    System.out.println("this is just loading in: " + arr[i]);
}
```

The key here is the `useDeliminator` method call. The `next` methods reads from the stream until it reaches the deliminator pattern. In this case, it is `\n`, a new line. Please use the new line character of your OS.

Answer (score -1):

This may be off point, but have you tried just using `array.add(scanner.next())` and looping until `scanner.hasNext()` returns false?